# How can I know the application is link to wifi or ethernet use java?

Tags: java, desktop-application, ethernet

I want detect network is wifi or ethernet at mac and windows.

```
NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()
```

This code can get the name of the networkinterface,but I don't know the network is wifi or ethernet.Please help me....

Comment: I would guess that you could get all the Network Interfaces, then use something like ping to see if they will communicate with another computer.

Comment: @Sedrick How can I know If the ip communicate with another computer is wifi or ethernet?

Comment: I try to ping the wifi IP and ethernet IP,they doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot know, you're not supposed to need to know, in application code. At the level Java applications run, there is no difference between networks, all you have is a TCP/IP stack and you can't determine based on that what kind of network you're working on.

You'd have to write something in native code that interfaces with low level operating system functionality (and don't ask me what or how, it's dependent on operating system obviously) to get that information.

Answer (score 1):

(If I understand your question) You may be able to try something like looking at the `Local Address` of different `Network Interfaces`. If a `wlan` has a private `IP Address`, you could assume it's connected to the network using wireless technology. If an `eth` has a private `IP Address`, you could assume it's connected to the network via ethernet. I don't know if this is 100% effective. This is not my area.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SocketException {

        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        for (NetworkInterface netint : Collections.list(nets))
            displayInterfaceInformation(netint);
    }

    static void displayInterfaceInformation(NetworkInterface netint) {
        try {
            NetworkInterface nif = netint;
            if(nif==null){
                System.err.println("Error getting the Network Interface");
                return;
            }

            Enumeration<InetAddress> nifAddresses = nif.getInetAddresses();
            InetSocketAddress inetAddr= new InetSocketAddress(nifAddresses.nextElement(),0);

            System.out.println("Interface: " + nif.getName());
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(inetAddr);
            System.out.println(socket.getLocalAddress());
            System.out.println("");
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException ex)
        {
            //System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
     }
}
```

**Output**

```
Interface: lo
/127.0.0.1

Interface: eth4 //Number changed!
/131.555.555.55
```

Looking at this output, I would assume that `eth4` has a network connection.